# How to find all complex numbers and roots of z in cubic equations

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, cubics

I am having difficulty solving complex number questions involving cubic roots an example of one such question is written below:

> How to find all complex numbers and roots of $z$ such that $z^3+4iz=0$?

Any help or clarification would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried factoring out a $z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $z^3+4iz=0\iff z(z^2+4i)=0$